# Metal shader kernel produces half alpha

Tags: metal

I have a no-op Metal compute shader implemented as:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void doNothing(
  texture2d<half, access::read> inTexture [[ texture (0) ]],
  texture2d<half, access::read_write> outTexture [[ texture (1) ]],
  uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
) {
  outTexture.write(inTexture.read(gid), gid);
}
```

I would expect this to just copy `inTexture` pixels into `outTexture`.  It seems like this is copying the pixels over correctly, but the alpha values are reduced by half.  Anyone know why this would be happening and how to fix it?

The input texture is created by the default device's texture loader from a `CGImage`, and the output texture is created using the `.rgba8Unorm_srgb` pixel type, the input texture's width/height, and mipmapped disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Of course once I resort to asking on StackOverflow, I figure out the answer.  Updating to the default `.rgba8Unorm` pixel format fixes this.